# Produce a graph of words from a corpus

Tags: r, quanteda

Creating a corpus from this process:

```
mystopwords <- c("can")
myDfm <- myCorpus %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart"), mystopwords))  %>%
  dfm(verbose = FALSE)
```

Is there any possibility to produce a graph like [this one](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/quanteda%3A-An-R-package-for-the-quantitative-of-data-Benoit-Watanabe/f1a210051a89f06fdb90f50a09f78ddb87bf308f/figure/0)

Comment: Just look at the documentation: https://tutorials.quanteda.io/basic-operations/fcm/fcm/

Comment: And `quanteda.textplots::textplot_network()`.